# Plotting data with variable frequency vs elapsed time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, timedelta

I have a dataset in pandas with measurements acquired with varying sample time.
I'm trying to plot the data vs. elapsed time, but time axis gets messed up.

I've found [info](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15067) that use of `.autofmt_xdate()` should solve the issue, but works only for data with fixed sampling frequency. In case of my data the x axis is entirely missing any labels.

a simple example of both cases

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx1 = pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:00', '00:00:30', '00:01:00', '00:01:30', '00:02:00'])
idx2 = pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:01', '00:00:30', '00:01:00', '00:01:30', '00:02:00'])
vals = range(5)
s1= pd.Series(vals, idx1)
s2= pd.Series(vals, idx2)

# Labels on x are ok
plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_title('fixed frequency f=30s')
s1.plot()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()

# Labels on x are messed up
plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_title('variable frequency')
s2.plot()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You example works fine for me with the xtick labels on both the plots

Comment: I can reproduce on matplotlib 2.2.3

Comment: I'm using Pandas version: 0.23.4; Matplotlib version: 2.2.3
Result I'm getting looks like that: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25963560/45159048-09cfae00-b1e6-11e8-9bc2-3ff8372e2344.png

Any suggestions what to do/check?

Comment: It looks like [this is the relevant issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18910) which is still unsolved.